# WCF session not closing after calling Close or Abort

Tags: c#, wcf, session, nettcpbinding

my server-client app uses WCF's sessions and is annotated as stated below:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

It communicates through a duplex NetTcpBinding and uses Message security:

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="WCFSecurityBinding" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="00:00:10"  closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="52428800" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="01:00:00"/>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

Everything works well, but I want to close the session manually under certain circumstances. I'm OK with the fact I cannot close the session from the server side. So I tried to force close the session from the client.
My very simple scenario is ([S] for server and [C] for client):

1. [S] start host app
2. [C] connect to [S] and initiate session
3. [C] close the session
4. [S] handle the InstanceContext.Closing event
5. [C] access some method from the session and get an exception.

So the number three is interesting for me.
I tried call proxy.Close() and proxy.Abort() as well as DuplexChannelFactory.Close(). Nothing worked for me - the handler (point 4) was never called and the session was still alive as prove point 5 when I was able to obtain data from server. I have not been able to find anything else than Close and Abort. Am I missing something?

The only two ways to achieve my behavior that have worked for me are:

1. raising an exception (very dirty)
2. add a special CloseSession method to the service with IsTerminating=true modifier. This is pretty cool, however, I wanted to use something from the WCF's infrastructure.

-EDIT
I have tried various methods:

```
        try
        {
            _proxy.Close();
        }
        catch (FaultException)
        {
            _proxy.Abort();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException)
        {
            _proxy.Abort();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            _proxy.Abort();
        }
```

Or

```
DuplexChannelFactory<...> dcf...
...
dcf.Close();
dcf.Abort();
Close();
Abort();
```

Nothing works and no exception throws.

Comment: Could you post your code to show how you are closing your service?

Comment: I added some snippets I have recently used. I'm not sure you wanted directly this.? When the whole client app is closing I'm doing nothing - I believe the client as well as the connection is disposed and WCF does all the work. And it appears to work this way - if I close the app, the Closing event handler fires on the server.

Comment: Can you write up a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating steps 1-5 and which does not cause a exception that we could just copy and paste in to our computers and just run?

Comment: @JanDrozen, I am experiencing the same issue, did you manage to find a solution? Thanks!